# VBA String Comparison

Tags: c#, vba, compare, string-comparison

currently I'm trying to convert a function (to compare to String and check the match percentage)  from C# to VBA.

C#:

```
 public static double CompareStrings(string str1, string str2)
    {
        List<string> pairs1 = WordLetterPairs(str1.ToUpper());
        List<string> pairs2 = WordLetterPairs(str2.ToUpper());

        int intersection = 0;
        int union = pairs1.Count + pairs2.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < pairs1.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < pairs2.Count; j++)
            {
                if (pairs1[i] == pairs2[j])
                {
                    intersection++;
                    pairs2.RemoveAt(j);//Must remove the match to prevent "GGGG" from appearing to match "GG" with 100% success

                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return (2.0 * intersection) / union;
    }

    private static List<string> WordLetterPairs(string str)
    {
        List<string> AllPairs = new List<string>();

        // Tokenize the string and put the tokens/words into an array
        string[] Words = Regex.Split(str, @"\s");

        // For each word
        for (int w = 0; w < Words.Length; w++)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Words[w]))
            {
                // Find the pairs of characters
                String[] PairsInWord = LetterPairs(Words[w]);

                for (int p = 0; p < PairsInWord.Length; p++)
                {
                    AllPairs.Add(PairsInWord[p]);
                }
            }
        }

        return AllPairs;
    }

    private static string[] LetterPairs(string str)
    {
        int numPairs = str.Length - 1;

        string[] pairs = new string[numPairs];

        for (int i = 0; i < numPairs; i++)
        {
            pairs[i] = str.Substring(i, 2);
        }

        return pairs;
    }
```

My VBA Conversion:

```
Option Explicit


Function CompareStrings(str1 As String, str2 As String)
    Dim pairs1 As New Collection
    Dim pairs2 As New Collection
    pairs1 = WordLetterPairs(UCase(str1))
    pairs2 = WordLetterPairs(UCase(str2))
    Dim intersection, union, i, j As Integer
    intersection = 0
    union = pairs1.Count + pairs2.Count

    For i = 0 To pairs1.Count
        For j = 0 To pairs2.Count
            If pairs1.Item(i) = pairs2.Item(i) Then
                 intersection = intersection + 1
                 pairs2.Remove (j)
                 Exit For
            End If

        Next j
    Next i
CompareStrings = ((2 * intersection) / union)
End Function

Function WordLetterPairs(str As String)
  Dim AllPairs As New Collection
  Dim words() As String
  words = SplitRe(str, "\s", True)
  Dim w As Integer
  For w = 0 To UBound(words)
    If Len(Trim(words(w))) = 0 Then
        Dim PairsInWord() As String
        PairsInWord = LetterPairs(words(w))
        For p = 0 To PairsInWord.Count
            AllPairs.Add (PairsInWord(p))
        Next p
    End If
  Next w
  WordLetterPairs = AllPairs
End Function
Public Function SplitRe(text As String, pattern As String, Optional ignorecase As Boolean) As String()
  Static re As Object
  If re Is Nothing Then
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    re.Global = True
    re.MultiLine = True
  End If
  re.ignorecase = ignorecase
  re.pattern = pattern
  SplitRe = Strings.Split(re.Replace(text, vbNullChar), vbNullChar)
End Function

Public Function LetterPairs(ByVal str As String)
Dim numPairs, w As Integer
numPairs = Len(str) - 1
Dim pairs(numPairs) As String
For w = 0 To numPairs
pairs(w) = Mid(str, w, 2)
Next w
End Function
Sub Schaltfläche1_Klicken()
 MsgBox (CompareStrings("LOL", "L"))
End Sub
```

I'm getting an error in the first line of CompareStrings, "Parameter is not optional". What did I convert wrong?

Comment: Which line does this happen

Comment: pairs1 = WordLetterPairs(UCase(str1))

Comment: try changing  pairs1 = WordLetterPairs(UCase(str1)) to Set  pairs1 = WordLetterPairs(UCase(str1)). You have to use the Set keyword when assigning object variables.

Comment: Try making Function WordLetterPairs(str As String) as Collection and using set when assigning value. Also keep in mind Dimming like this: intersection, union, i, j As Integer will mean only j will be an integer, the rest are Variant types when Dimmed.

Comment: @RyanWildry yes good catch. it should still work as it will return a variant, but explicit datatypes are always better.

Comment: None of your functions have a return type, @RyanWildry suggest that WordLetterPairs should return a Collection, but you should properly declare the return type of the other functions too. BTW since WorldLetterPairs returns it's own Collection, you don't have to declare pairs1 and pairs2  `as New Collection`, you should remove the `New`.

Comment: i'm used to programm object oriented with c#, I don't get along with that kind of unrestrictive concept VBA has. But thanks to you guys, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do as desired?  Are you wishing to return the non/matches?

```
Function StringCompare(str1 As String, str2 As String) As Double

Dim intLength As Integer
Dim iLetter As Integer

intLength = Len(str1)

For i = 1 To intLength
    If Mid(str1, i, 1) = Mid(str2, i, 1) Then
        StringCompare = StringCompare + 1
    End If
Next

StringCompare = StringCompare / intLength

End Function
```

Comment: Kind of the right direction but the c# is a bit pickier